# Asp Core Oidc Client with IdentityServer 4 AccessToken Expire handling

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

Ive a asp Core MVC Application which is connected to a IdentityServer 4 token service

In order to get the expire handelt i want to store the expiry of the current Token.

for this i wanted to use the TokenValidated event like this:

```
options.Events.OnTokenValidated = msg =>
{
        var expire = msg.TokenEndpointResponse.ExpiresIn;
}
```

but the TokenEndpointResponse is null

With IdentityServer 3 I had a `exp` claim which i cant see in v4 (neither in the quickstart sample)

what am i missing and what is the intended way to get the expiry in order to refresh the tokens in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft is stripping the exp claim now by default. Do

`options.ClaimActions.Remove("exp");`

On the OIDC handler options.